# string.prototype.localeCompare(), script modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, sorting

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>  
            Sort a list alphabetically 
        </title> 

        <script src =  
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script> 
    </head>  

    <body>  
        <button> 
                click here 
            </button> 

        <ul> 
            <li>Geeks</li> 
            <li>Sosna</li> 
            <li>Zebra</li> 
            <li>GeeksForGeeks</li>
          <li><h1>G</h1></li> 
            <li><h1>F</h1></li> 
            <li>Arbuz</li> 
            <li><h1>A</h1></li>
          <li>Łódź</li> 
            <li><h1>Ł</h1></li>
          <li>ósmy</li> 
            <li><h1>Ó</h1></li> 
          <li>święty</li> 
            <li><h1>Ś</h1></li> 
          <li>ärgern</li> 
            <li><h1>Ä</h1></li> 
          <li>Österreich</li> 
            <li><h1>Ö</h1></li> 
          <li>Überraschung</li> 
            <li><h1>Ü</h1></li> 
        </ul> 

        <script> 
            function Ascending_sort(a, b) { 
                return ($(b).text().toUpperCase()) <  
                    ($(a).text().toUpperCase()) ? 1 : -1;  
            } 
            $('button').on('click', function() { 
                $("ul li").sort(Ascending_sort).appendTo('ul'); 
            });                  
        </script>  
    </body>  
</html>
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/rudolph-reti/pen/dyPzXER

I just started learning JavaScript. I can't handle it alone. I would like the list to be sorted using [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) function. Could somebody help me put it into the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) already returns the correct Number value that `.sort()` expects, so  you don't need to worry about doing that yourself

From the Docs, the Return value of `.localeCompare()`:

> A negative number if the reference string occurs before the compare string; positive if the reference string occurs after the compare string; 0 if they are equivalent.

Your code with `.localeCompare()` would be as follows:

```js
function Ascending_sort(a, b) {
  b = $(b).text().trim().toUpperCase();
  a = $(a).text().trim().toUpperCase();

  return b.localeCompare(a);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("ul li").sort(Ascending_sort).appendTo('ul');
});
```

Following discussion in the chat, using a sort making use a string made more sense, and has been added to the snippet

```js
const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöüß";

function letterSort(a, b) {
  b = $(b).text().trim().toLowerCase();
  a = $(a).text().trim().toLowerCase();
  
  // Find the first position were the strings do not match
  let position = 0;
  
  while(a[position] === b[position]) {
      // If both are the same don't swap
      if(!a[position] && !b[position]) return 0;
      
      // Otherwise the shorter one goes first
      if(!a[position]) return 1;
      if(!b[position]) return -1;
      
      position++;
  }
  
  // Then sort by the characters position
  return alphabet.indexOf(a[position]) - alphabet.indexOf(b[position]);
}

$('button').on('click', function() {
  $("ul li").sort(letterSort).appendTo('ul');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button>Click here</button>

  <ul>
    <li>Geeks</li>
    <li>Sosna</li>
    <li>Zebra</li>
    <li>GeeksForGeeks</li>
    <li>
      <h1>G</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>F</h1>
    </li>
    <li>Arbuz</li>
    <li>
      <h1>A</h1>
    </li>
    <li>Łódź</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ł</h1>
    </li>
    <li>ósmy</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ó</h1>
    </li>
    <li>święty</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ś</h1>
    </li>
    <li>ärgern</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ä</h1>
    </li>
    <li>Österreich</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ö</h1>
    </li>
    <li>Überraschung</li>
    <li>
      <h1>Ü</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. List elements aren't alphabetically ordered. Now I see two lists: without <h1> and with <h1>. Both of them are in descending order. I need one list with ascending order.

Comment: If you want to swap the sort around, change the parameters around in Ascending_sort - Instead of `($(a).text().toUpperCase()).localeCompare(($(b).text().toUpperCase()))`, use `($(b).text().toUpperCase()).localeCompare(($(a).text().toUpperCase()))`

Comment: How to make "arbuz" after "A", "ärgern" after "Ä", "ósmy" after "Ó", "Österreich" after "Ö", etc.?

Comment: Not sure, but might be something in the options that you can change to get this result - currently trying some things but not having a ton of luck [Here is the link for the Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: I know this document. It's not a big problem. I'm just asking out of curiosity. Maybe it'll be useful in the future. Thanks once more! :)

Comment: It seems I need to use parameter sensitivity "accent", but how to put it? In example from documentation there is: console.log(a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {sensitivity: 'base'})); so my code should look like that: ($(a).text().toUpperCase()).localeCompare(($(b, {sensitivity: 'accent'}).text().toUpperCase())); but it doesn't work. What do I wrong?

Comment: I've changed the code slightly to be easier to edit, but that's the best I can do - I was trying this earlier and got no where. Instead of `en` you might need to use the locale that these characters are coming from, `fi` for example gives a different sort order; but I don't know what locale should be used for your case

Comment: I need sorting for polish and german. For polish it works good, but for german doesn't. I don't know why. All of umlauts (Ö, Ä, Ü) should go to the end of list, but they don't change their position. https://codepen.io/rudolph-reti/pen/dyPzXER I add "onload" in <body>.

Comment: Is that not just using 'de' as the locale? Sorts according to your 3rd comment in the snippet if I check on editor

Comment: I put: return b.localeCompare(a, 'de'); and nothing happened.

Comment: Please forget this 3 comment. German alphabet looks so: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Alphabet I need this sorting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205156/discussion-between-light-and-reti).

Comment: I've spent way too long trying to find the correct locale / intl code for the german language, but it turns out they have 3 different ways to sort depending on if it's Phonebook / Dictionary / Normal
LocaleCompare & intl.collactor doesn't take either of them
Const alphabet is a string where you can manually specify your sorting order, I've just typed in the german alphabet; if this is wrong for you, it should be simple enough to write the new order you want to the string

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the discussed changes

Answer (score 1):

try

```
function Ascending_sort(a, b) { 
            return $(b).text().localeCompare($(a).text()) 
        } 
        $('button').on('click', function() { 
            $("ul li").sort(Ascending_sort).appendTo('ul'); 
        });
```

Comment: It's good, but descending. And there is the same problem I mentioned in the comment above: "How to make "arbuz" after "A", "ärgern" after "Ä", "ósmy" after "Ó", "Österreich" after "Ö", etc.?"

Comment: swap the parameters around in ascending_sort, then you should have it ascending! for the arbuz after A thing, i would not take the headers into the sort aswell, but use another function to extract all existing start characters and put them into the dom!